# Dafny issue modifying array member of class

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

I'm trying to modify an array member of a class in Dafny. These modifications may include re-assigning the array member, modifying elements of the array member, or both. For example, consider the following class definition:

```
class Class {
    var arrayMember : array<int>
}
```

The following verifies, which both reassigns the member and modifies an element:

```
method verifies(obj : Class)
modifies obj, obj.arrayMember
{
    if (obj.arrayMember.Length < 5) {
        obj.arrayMember := new int[5](i => 0);
    }
    obj.arrayMember[4] := 3;
}
```

However, when I pull the code which re-assigns the array out into a separate method, I start to get issues:

```
method expandArray(obj : Class, size : nat)
modifies obj
ensures obj.arrayMember.Length >= size
{
    if (obj.arrayMember.Length < size) {
        obj.arrayMember := new int[size](i => 0);
    }
}

method doesNotVerify(obj : Class)
modifies obj, obj.arrayMember
{
    expandArray(obj, 5);
    obj.arrayMember[4] := 3;
}
```

Specifically, `obj.arrayMember[4] := 3` does not verify with `assignment might update an array element not in the enclosing context's modifies clause`. It seems to me that I should be able to modify `obj.arrayMember` as it is in the `modifies` clause of the method. I can only conclude that there must be something wrong with the `expandArray` method as the non-verifying method can be made to verify by inlining it (i.e. the first snippet of code I wrote, which verifies).

Any idea why this code won't verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `expandArray` is allowed to reassign the array to point to some other array, and Dafny is worried that it might have reassigned the array to point to some existing array that is not in the modifies clause of `doesNotVerify`. You can add additional postconditions to `expandArray` to tell Dafny that the method only assigns "fresh" (ie, newly allocated) arrays to the array member:

```
ensures obj.arrayMember == old(obj.arrayMember) || fresh(obj.arrayMember)
```

This says that either `expandArray` does not change which array `obj.arrayMember` points to, or, if it does change it, it changes it to point to a freshly allocated array, not some existing array.

---

If you want to go deeper into building mutable heap data structures in Dafny, I recommend checking out sections 0 and 1 of [Specification and Verification of Object-Oriented Software](http://leino.science/papers/krml190.pdf). (Note that this paper is quite old now, so some minor things are out of date. But the key ideas are there.) In particular, check out the `footprint` set and the `Valid` predicate to manage the "footprint" (all transitively reachable mutable references).

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. This did indeed fix the issue, and thanks for the learning resource.